# How do you append an element but also keep it in it's original position?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm looking for a way to copy the exact code of an element and move it to another element while keeping it in it's original place also.

I have some JS where basically you click on a picture, the picture will then be appended to a box. However, the picture completely moves. I want the picture to stay as well as be moved to the box as I am looking to grey it out instead of make it disappear.

I don't need specific answers, just a general javascript answer on how I can achieve this, thank you.

Comment: So you want the image to visually stay exactly at the same spot, but structurally, to belong to a different container, is that it? If so, I don't see any generic example for it.

Comment: do you want to relocate it in the DOM, or create a copy of it somewhere else on screen ?

Comment: No sorry the question wasn't clear. I wanted the element to be cloned and that clone be placed in another position in the DOM. @Rohit Arora answered my question and that has worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by creating a clone.

```
$('#div').append($('#image').clone())
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using jQuery have you tried `clone()`? - straight from the docs..

```
$( ".hello" ).clone().appendTo( ".goodbye" );
```

http://api.jquery.com/clone/

Answer (score 0):

You can get the html of the image and then copy it to the image container:

**javascript**

```
function addImageTo(element){
    var oldHTML = element.innerHTML;
    var appendHTML = document.getElementById('yourImage').innerHTML;

    element.innerHTML = oldHTML + appendHTML;
}
```

**JQuery**

```
function addImageTo(element){
    element.append($('#yourImage').innerHTML);
}
```

Comment: It is worth mentioning that the variable `element` must be a jQuery object.